# How to limit a date histogram aggregation of nested documents to a specific date range?

Tags: elasticsearch

**Version**

Using Elasticsearch `1.7.2`

**Objective**

I would like to create a graph of the number of predictions made by users per day for the last `n` days. In this case, 10 days.

**Current query**

```js
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "predictions": {
            "nested": {
                "path": "user_answers"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "predictions_over_time": {
                    "date_histogram": {
                        "field": "user_answers.created",
                        "interval": "day",
                        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd",
                        "min_doc_count": 0
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Issue**

This query will return a histogram but will return buckets for all available dates across all documents. It doesn't restrict to a specific date range.

**What have I tried?**

I've tried a number of approaches to solving this, all of which have failed.
* Range filter, then histogram that
* Date range aggregation, then histogram the buckets
* Using `extended_bounds` with, full dates, `now-10d` and also timestamps
* Trying a range filter inside the histogram aggregation

Any guidance would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`query` didn't work for me in that situation, what I used is a third aggs:

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "user_answers": {
            "nested": { "path": "user_answers" },
            "aggs": {
                "timed_user_answers": {
                    "filter": {
                        "range": {
                            "user_answers.created": {
                                "gte": "now",
                                "lte": "now -10d"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "predictions_over_time": {
                            "date_histogram": {
                                "field": "user_answers.created",
                                "interval": "day",
                                "format": "yyyy-MM-dd",
                                "min_doc_count": 0
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

One `aggs` specifies `nested`, one specifies `filter`, and the last specifies the actual aggregation. Don't know why this syntax makes sense, but you seem to not be able to use two on the same `aggs`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add a query. Query can be anything except from post_filter. It should be nested and contain date range. One of the ways is to define a constant score query. Inside constant score query, use a nested filter which should use a range filter.

```
{
  "query": {
    "constant_score": {
      "filter": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "user_answers",
           "filter": {
             "range": {
               "user_answers.created": {
                 "gte": "now",
                 "lte": "now -10d"
               }
             }
           }
        }
      }

    }
  }
}
```

Confirm if this works for you.

Comment: Where is the `date_histogram` aggregation supposed to go inside this filtered query? I don't need a query as the score is irrelevant.

Comment: Since you dont need score that's why I have used a constant score query. Secondly you want always want to restrict the documents going to aggregation by putting up a query/filter. Here the condition is between now and now -10 days. Thirdly, no the date_histogram aggregation is not supposed to go inside this filtered query.  Your complete query would be combination of yours and mine query and you can remove the min doc count. Cheers

Comment: No, this does not work. Also I cannot remove the `min_doc_count` because then I'd not include dates which have 0 matches, making my graph incorrect.

Comment: @DavidYell - I bet my query is working with the aggregation you mentioned. 100 bounties !!! say what? And with my query with a better performance compared to the third aggregated answer. You just can't down vote someone's answer like that. Let's hear from you.

Comment: For your reference, here is the mapping : https://gist.github.com/piyushGoyal2/448696bd1c9e288f2c57 ... here is the document .. https://gist.github.com/piyushGoyal2/28f28199af92a95734b5 and here is the query ..... https://gist.github.com/piyushGoyal2/28f28199af92a95734b5